# Collapse multiple empty lines in content to a single line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, text, replace, find, notepad++

Is there a way in Notepad++ to collapse multiple empty lines in content to a single line?

For example, from this:

```
Line0
Line1


Line2



Line3

Line4
Line5
```

to this:

```
Line0
Line1

Line2

Line3

Line4
Line5
```

I would like to run a replacement on a folder with "Find In Files" function; is there a way to be able to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[\r\n]{2,}
```

You can replace by `\n` or `\n\n`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tD0dU9/12

EDIT:

use `(?:\r\n){2,}` for notepadd ++

Comment: With this solution if two lines are consecutive (eg. Line0 and Line1), with the replace is added a blank line between them; while I wish that the blank line is not added, but only removed if excess. See example.

Comment: Mmm...on demo page is ok but when I try to run on Notepad++ seems not work..it matches every endline

Comment: Thanks! Now seems ok...a last thing: Is there a way to do the same thing on the line even if there are spaces?